# livewire wire:click function doesnt put a product in the cart that i want

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

hey guys i got a problem with my button, it doesnt do the function that i want nor give me any error so i dont know what happen
here are some of my cart controller code

```
$products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

        $condition = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition([
            'name' => 'pajak',
            'type' => 'tax',
            'target' => 'total',
            'value' => $this->tax,
            'order' => 1
        ]);

        \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->condition($condition);
        $items = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getContent()->sortBy(function ($cart){
            return $cart->attributes->get('added_at');
        });

        if(\Cart::isEmpty()){
            $cartData = [];
        }else{
            foreach($items as $item){
                $cart[] = [
                    'rowId' => $row->id,
                    'name' => $item->name,
                    'pricesingle' => $item->harga,
                    'price' => $item->getPriceSum(),
                ];
            }
            
            $cartData = collect($cart);
        }

        $sub_total = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getSubTotal();
        $total = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getTotal();

        $newCondition = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getCondition('pajak');
        $pajak = $newCondition->getCalculatedValue($sub_total);

        $summary = [
            'sub_total' => $sub_total,
            'pajak' => $pajak,
            'total' => $total
        ];

        return view('livewire.cart-component', [
            'products' => $products,
            'carts' => $cartData,
            'summary' => $summary
        ]);
    }

    public function addItem($id){
        $rowId = "Cart".$id;
        $cart = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getContent();
        $cekItemId = $cart->whereIn('id', $rowId);

        if($cekItemId->IsNotEmpty()){
            \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->update($rowId, [
                'quantity' =>[
                    'relative' => true,
                    'value' => 1
                ]
            ]);
        }else{
            $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
            \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->add([
                'id' => "Cart".$product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'price' => $product->harga,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'attributes' =>[
                    'added_at' => Carbon::now() 
                ],
            ]);
        }
```

and here are the product blade code

```
    <div class="container project-items mt-4 mb-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            @foreach ($products as $product)
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 mb-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('produkListJasa') }}/{{$product->image}}" alt="{{$product->name}}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="text-center font-weight-bold card-text">{{$product->name}}</p>
                            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold wrap-price"><span class="product-price">Rp. {{$product->harga}}</span></div>
                            <!-- Buttonnya percobaan doang  -->
                            <button wire:click="addItem({{$product->id}})" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here are my cart blade code so that when product button clicked, the product and price goes in to this cart blade

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-center">Cart</h2>
                <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hovered">
                    <thread>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thread>
                </table>
                <tbody>
                    @forelse($carts as $index=>$cart)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$cart['name']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$cart['harga']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @empty
                        <td colspan="3"><h6 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Empty Cart</h6></td>
                        <div class="image d-flex mt-5 justify-content-center">
                            <img src="foto/cart_empty.png" alt="cart visual" width="1200" height="800">
                        </div>
                    @endforelse
                </tbody>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i dont know if its from the livewire or laravel or anything, im still learning about this and just following some tutorial video
i hope anyone can help me
thank you

Comment: new update, try to use dd to check if the button actually work and connected to the controller or not, found it it does not connected, sad

Comment: another update found out its only to the addItem function in controller that didnt work with the button, still looking for solution...

Answer (score 0):

Check or dd in addItem method the results of every statement. I saw here something that you have to check:

```
$rowId = "Cart".$id;
$cart = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getContent();
$cekItemId = $cart->whereIn('id', $rowId);
```

As long as I know, whereIn receive an array as second parameter and you don't. So ckeck for all this

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply and sorry for late respon, i try to delete all the line in all addItem function when i still use wire:click, sadly it doesnt do anything, so i think the problem are on the livewire becasue when i try to use ```href="{{ route('add.item', $product->id) }}"``` instead, it works fine

Comment: And in Network and Console tag something happen? Put the button inside div, and check if the page is loading the @(livewireStyles and livewireScripts)

Comment: thank you for another reply, netwrok and console tag does nothing, i did tried input the button inside div and nothing work, and yes livewireStlyes and livewireScript been loaded in the page source

Comment: But you have two components...cart and product, so as long as I can now see addItem method is in cart component and the button is in product blade...Am I right until here?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes

Comment: And there is product a nested component from cart??? How you're trying to manage make click in product blade and call a method of cart component?

Comment: yess problem solved by your comment thank you soo much mr prospero !